# execute "terraform apply" with google provider, error(oauth2: cannot fetch token)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp

I've been grappling with this issue for two days now:

I followed the instructions in the course to create a project service account.  I assigned the necessary permissions (BigQuery Admin,Compute Admin,Compute Network Admin,Organization Administrator,Storage Admin,Storage Object Admin,,Viewer)to the service account and placed the key in a subfolder named "keys" within the same folder as the main.tf file. In the "provider" block of the main.tf file, I set the credentials to "./keys/my-creds.json".

## **However, when I execute "terraform apply," it displays error：**

```
google_storage_bucket.demo-bucket: Creating...
google_storage_bucket.demo-bucket: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_storage_bucket.demo-bucket: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
google_storage_bucket.demo-bucket: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: Post "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?alt=json&prettyPrint=false&project=coherent-ascent-379901": oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token": dial tcp 172.217.163.42:443: i/o timeout
```

## here is the content of my main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "5.13.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = "./keys/my-creds.json" # Credentials only needs to be set if you do not have the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS set
  project     = "coherent-ascent-379901"
  region      = "us-central1"
}



resource "google_storage_bucket" "demo-bucket" {
  name          = "coherent-ascent-379901-terra-bucket"
  location      = "US"
  force_destroy = true

  lifecycle_rule {
    condition {
      age = 2 //days
    }
    action {
      type = "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload"
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone had a similar issue?

It seems like  the OAuth2 token retrieval issue. Here's a summary of my actions:

1.Checked the authentication status using `gcloud auth list` and confirmed that both the service account and user account are active

2.Updated the SDK to the latest version using `gcloud components update`

3. Successfully obtained an access token by running `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

4.Attempted to reauthorize by running `gcloud auth application-default login`

## after trying these actions, when I execute "terraform apply," the error persists.

Comment: The error means you have a network problem. Probably an anti-virus or add blocking software or similar. Review what is installed on your system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Because Google is not accessible in my country, I am using a VPN. I'm not sure if this is the cause of the issue. but I don't know how to test this problem.

Comment: Please put that detail in your question. Plus routing details for your VPN

Comment: thanks,In my country,  I can't use google things without a third-part VPN, so I can't route details for the VPN I'm using, since I know nothing about it.

Comment: @JohnHanley hey, thanks for your response, I have already worked out this issue.The issue was with the network.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the network. Google is not accessible in my country, I am using a VPN. And The terminal program does not automatically follow the system proxy and requires separate proxy configuration settings.I opened a Enhanced Mode in Clash, which is a VPN app, and 'terraform apply' works!

I hope this question can help someone  who is grappling with this same issue.